# Create multiply calendars and sync them to google calendar

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am looking for a way to organize the delivery of events to the users of my platform.

I have, say, 10,000 users who have different events going on. Events can be canceled, postponed, or created.

The task is to enable such users to subscribe to a calendar unique to each of them, and to make sure that all changes are synchronized in their Google calendar.

If I understood correctly, the way when we pre-create calendars in Google Calendar and then sign users there is not suitable, since there is a limit on the number of such calendars in the Google account.

Instead, I'm looking for a way to organize a calendar in CSV format available via a link, as I believe.
It should be a dynamic structure that I can update from my platform and somehow automatically update this data in the user's final calendar.

A separate question is how exactly to authorize the user's calendar, whether it is safe, and whether it is possible to make auto-subscription work not for the entire calendar, but for a calendar specially created in the user's calendar, in which all events will be displayed.

Am I thinking right?
What solutions could you suggest?